# simple refinerycms custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I'm trying to create a very simple route without the overhead of a full engine. Basically, we're making requests to a third party api, but want to ajax the request to stay on one page. I could be doing something incredibly stupid, but have been at this for a few hours now and have chalked it up to needing some help.

config/routes.rb

```
Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  get 'legislature/find' => 'legislatures#find', as: 'find'
end
```

app/controllers/refinery/legislatures_controller.rb

```
module Refinery
  class LegislaturesController < ::ApplicationController

    def find
      # parse serialized string here
      # binding.pry
    end
  end
end
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); 

  $('#test').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this)
    var data = self.serialize();
    console.log("I GOT HERE!");

    $.get('legislature/find', data, function(response) {
      console.log("BUT I CAN'T GET HERE!");
    });
  });
});
```

Form is one-input that takes in a zip code with an id of #test.